# WordPress - Get Comments by Meta Data?

Tags: wordpress, comments

I have developed a custom plugin.

I need a comment option for my plugin.

I have passed a key value as meta key.

In the comment list, it displays all the comments for the particular page, but I want it to display the comments based on the meta key.

Is this possible?

Comment: absolutely. check out https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)